# Extract date from String java

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat, date-parsing

I have a String with several dates, for example:

```
[20-Jul-2012 5:11:36,670 UTC PM, 20-Jul-2012 5:11:36,683 UTC PM]
```

How do I read this string and extract each date? I'm using the `SimpleDateFormat` class to create a regex.

```
SimpleDateFormat format2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS z a");
```

I've tried :

I've just did, to get the first one and it changes the format and the timezone:

```
ParsePosition parsePos = new ParsePosition(1);
SimpleDateFormat format2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS z a");
System.out.println(format2.parse(entry.getValue().toString(), parsePos)) ;
```

Output : Fri Jul 20 06:11:36 BST 2012

Comment: are those dates separated by commas ??

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
 parsePos = new ParsePosition(1);
 while((date = format2.parse(yourString, parsePos)!=null){
      //use date
 }
```

Comment: I've just did, to get the first one and it changes the timezone: ParsePosition parsePos = new ParsePosition(1);
SimpleDateFormat format2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS z a"); Output : Fri Jul 20 06:11:36 BST 2012      System.out.println(format2.parse(entry.getValue().toString(), parsePos)) ;

Answer (score 1):

### java.time

The question uses `SimpleDateFormat` which was the correct thing to do in 2012. In Mar 2014, the `java.util` date-time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` were supplanted by the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html). Since then, it is strongly recommended to stop using the legacy date-time API.

**Solution using the modern date-time API**:

```
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d-MMM-uuuu h:m:s,SSS VV a", Locale.ENGLISH);
        Stream.of(
                    "20-Jul-2012 5:11:36,670 UTC PM",
                    "20-Jul-2012 5:11:36,683 UTC PM"
            )
            .map(s -> ZonedDateTime.parse(s, parser))
            .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
2012-07-20T17:11:36.670Z[UTC]
2012-07-20T17:11:36.683Z[UTC]
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/1eBG1c)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.